# How do I use Android's DropDownPreference?

Tags: java, android, xml, preferences, preferenceactivity

I'm trying to build a preference screen with a [DropDownPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/DropDownPreference.html). Initially I was using the following in my gradle file `compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:25.3.1'` but switched to `compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.3.1'` when I noticed the DropDownPreference was included in v7, not v14 (I thought v14 might also include everything from v7, but I guess not?). My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:title="@string/pref_title"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="pref_video"
        android:title="@string/pref_video_title">

        <android.support.v7.preference.DropDownPreference
            android:key="pref_video_quality"
            android:title="@string/pref_video_quality"
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary_video_quality"
            android:entries="@array/pref_entries_video_quality"
            android:entryValues="@array/pref_entries_video_quality" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

I've also just tried `DropDownPreference` as the tag. Nothing seems to work. I always get an `Error inflating class DropDownPreference` error when I try to go to my preference screen in the app.

Any idea how I can use this DropDownPreference? Thanks!

Edit: Adding error message:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.int_a.giantbombforandroid/com.app.int_a.giantbombforandroid.main.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.preference.DropDownPreference cannot be cast to android.preference.Preference
```

Edit: SettingsActivity declaration in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".main.SettingsActivity"
  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
  android:theme="@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material">
</activity>
```

Comment: Hey @intA, You are right and v14 includes v7. I just set up a test project and I got `DropDownPreferences` to work with your layout. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: That's strange. Currently the settings activity works fine if I use a basic `ListPreference`, but as soon as I replace it with either `DropDownPreference` or the fully qualified `android.support.v7.preference.DropDownPreference` I get the error that I've added to my original post. I also get a highlight in the XML file saying that this element is not allowed here.

Comment: Okay, I'm doing something differently. My `SettingsActivity` extends `AppCompatActivity` and I add a fragment that extends `PreferenceFragmentCompat`. It's the recommended way of doing preferences.

Comment: Oh, that's it! Didn't realize the compat versions were recommended. Though now I'm getting the following error regarding my theme: ` java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must specify preferenceTheme in theme`. I did specify a theme for the SettingsActivity in the manifest, but does one need to be set for the fragment as well? I put the Activity's declaration from my AndroidManifest.xml in my original post.

Comment: Yeah you need to specify the preferenceTheme in your styles.xml. I'll add an answer with all my files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow up from my comment. Code is in Kotlin btw :)

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
</style>
```

**activity_settings.xml**

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
        android:id="@+id/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frame"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**prefs.xml** has exactly what you have in your question

**Settings.kt**

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)

        setupActionBar()

        if (savedInstanceState == null)
            supportFragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.frame, SettingsFragment.newInstance())
                    .commit()
    }

    private fun setupActionBar() {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }

    class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

        override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

            val actionBar = (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar

            actionBar?.title = preferenceScreen.title
        }

        override fun onCreatePreferences(bundle: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {

            // Using this method instead of addPreferencesFromXml so we can specify the root preference screen
            // This way, navigating to a new screen is as simple as calling SettingsFragment.newInstance("new_root")
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs, rootKey)
        }

        companion object {

            fun newInstance(rootKey: String = "root") = SettingsFragment().apply {

                // When you pass a string argument with key ARG_PREFERENCE_ROOT, 
                // PreferenceFragmentCompat picks it up and supplies it as an argument to onCreatePreferences
                arguments = Bundle().apply { putString(ARG_PREFERENCE_ROOT, rootKey) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the end result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. After taking a look at your code I realized the only thing keeping mine from working was that I was using `onCreate()` in my SettingsFragment instead of `onActivityCreated()`. I did not have to include an activity_settings.xml file nor anything related to the action bar, is there a reason you have those? Are they just recommended?

Comment: Also, when I was creating my settings_activity.xml file for testing it forced me to include the android namespace as well as `layout_height` and `layout_width` for each element. How did you get away with not including this? Unless you just omitted them for brevity?

Comment: Yes I omitted them for brevity. I added only the most important bits. What I did in onActivityCreated was just to set the title for the activity.

Comment: The gist of the solution is
1. Make sure `preferenceTheme` is included
2. Create a fragment that extends `PreferenceFragnentCompat` and add it to any normal activity.
3. Use `DropdownPreferenceFragment` exactly how you did in your question.

Comment: Where are you defining High/Medium/Low??

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample in XML

```
<DropDownPreference
    android:key="dropdown"
    android:title="@string/title_dropdown_preference"
    android:entries="@array/entries"
    app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true"
    android:entryValues="@array/entry_values"/>
```